# Prove the equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Prove that
$$\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\left(x^2+\dfrac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\right)\text{d}x=\frac{e^{-2a}\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
Assume that the equation is true for $a=0.$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$I(a):=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\left(x^2+\dfrac{a^2}{x^2}\right)}\text{d}x$$
$$\frac{dI}{da}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\left(x^2+\dfrac{a^2}{x^2}\right)}\left(-\frac{2a}{x^2}\right)\text{d}x$$
Now substitute $y=\frac{a}{x}$, so $dy=-\frac{a}{y^2}$:
$$\frac{dI}{da}=2\int_{\text{sgn}(a)\cdot\infty}^{0}e^{-\left(\dfrac{a^2}{y^2}+y^2\right)}\text{d}y=-2\text{sgn}(a)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\dfrac{a^2}{y^2}+y^2\right)}\text{d}y=-2\text{sgn}(a)I$$
To obtain $I$ you just have to solve the simple ODE:
$$\frac{dI}{da}=-2\text{sgn}(a)I$$
with initial condition given by
$$I(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\ .$$
This gives you 
$$I(a)=\frac{e^{-2|a|}\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks. It is very clever. But can you elaborate a bit more on how you came up with the solution translating the original problem into solving an ODE?

Comment: Do you mean the explicit resolution of the ODE?

Comment: No. I can read your solution. What I asked was the idea behind your solution.

Comment: The idea behind the solution is the technique of differentiation under the integral sign(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign#General_examples): when you have an integral that depend on a parameter, you can derive the integral w.r.t. that parameter and sometimes you obtain a much simpler integral. In this particular case the trick is to notice that after the derivation, getting rid of the extra factor you obtain by a change of variable you get again the first integral. This allow you to find a relation between $I$ and its derivative, i.e. the ODE.

Comment: I get it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In general
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-ax^2-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)\,dx&=\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{ax^2}\right)\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x^2-2\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+\frac{b}{ax^2}+2\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2-2\sqrt{ab}\right)\,dx\\
&=\exp(-2\sqrt{ab})\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dx\\
\end{align}
$$
The trick to solve the last integral is by setting
$$
I=\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dx.
$$
Let $t=-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\;\rightarrow\;x=-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\;\rightarrow\;dx=\frac{1}{t^2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\,dt$, then
$$
I_t=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\int_{t=0}^\infty \frac{\exp\left(-a\left(-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+t\right)^2\right)}{t^2}\,dt.
$$
Let $t=x\;\rightarrow\;dt=dx$, then
$$
I_t=\int_{t=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dt.
$$
Adding the two $I_t$s yields
$$
2I=I_t+I_t=\int_{t=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)\exp\left(-a\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dt.
$$
Let $s=t-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\;\rightarrow\;ds=\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)dt$ and for $0<t<\infty$ is corresponding to $-\infty<s<\infty$, then
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{s=-\infty}^\infty e^{-as^2}\,ds=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},
$$
where $I$ is a [Gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html). Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\exp(-2\sqrt{ab})\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dx
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}}.
\end{align}
$$
In our case, put $a=1$ and $b=a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\bracks{x^{2} + {a^{2} \over x^2}}}\,\dd x
     ={\root{\pi} \over 2}\,\expo{-2\verts{a}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\bracks{x^{2} + {a^{2} \over x^2}}}\,\dd x}\
> =\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-\verts{a}\bracks{%
> {x^{2} \over \verts{a}} + {\verts{a} \over x^2}}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{x \equiv \root{\verts{a}}\expo{\theta}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-2\verts{a}\cosh\pars{2\theta}}
> \root{\verts{a}}\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=\root{\verts{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \expo{-2\verts{a}\bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}
> \bracks{\cosh\pars{\theta} + \sinh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=\root{\verts{a}}\expo{-2\verts{a}}\
> \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \expo{-4\verts{a}\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}}\cosh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}
> ^{\ds{t\ \equiv\ \sinh\pars{\theta}}}\
> =\root{\verts{a}}\expo{-2\verts{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \expo{-4\verts{a}t^{2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\root{\verts{a}}\expo{-2\verts{a}}\,{1 \over 2\root{\verts{a}}}\
> \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-t^{2}}\,\dd t}^{\ds{=\ \root{\pi}}}\
> =\
> \color{#66f}{\Large{\root{\pi} \over 2}\,\expo{-2\verts{a}}}
> \end{align}